# scrollTo plugin error "Object [object Object] has no method 'scrollTo' "

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, scroll

I am trying to use scrollTo plugin , but with no luck , I am getting this error

Object [object Object] has no method 'scrollTo'

the script scrollTo included to the page ...

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.scrollTo-1.4.3.1.js"></script>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
```

I am calling it like

```
  $("#nav-next").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#slider").scrollTo(1300, 0);
    });
```

And this is Div I am trying to apply scroll on it:

```
  <div id="slider">
<div class="static-panel" id="static-panel">

  .... Images here 
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you use [.scrollTop()](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)?

Answer (score 0):

Try updating this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>//--^^^^^^---this
```

and try with this:

```
<script src="http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/js/jquery.scrollTo-min.js">
</script>
```

may be there are issues with the path of `scrollTo` plugin.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't helps :-(

Answer (score 0):

It was the problem with 2 versions of Jquery loaded in the same time...

Asp.Net mvc default template adding 2 lines

```
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

And this loads jquery 1.7.1